Horror movie about a man seduced by a girl and finds out that she had gills
I'm looking for a horror movie but am unable to remember much of it at all other than a couple scenes. No actors or date but it's a horror for sure made more than 5 years ago at least! 
One scene where a man is lost in a mansion and finds a room with a pretty girl in the bed and is seduced by her and starts making out with her to horrifically find she has gills (as in fish gills) and is terrified to find her lower half of her body is all octopus tentacles. 
Another scene he is hiding under maybe a porch or something and he sees a *demon/monster go past that is just the top half of a body dragging itself along. 
That's all I remember but it's bugging me that I can't remember this movie so any help is appreciated!

I think the whole movie takes place on land. It's raining in it as well. As if that even helps haha. Thank you so much though.

Please don't add additional details as comments. Edit your post to add them.
